# Is there a way to display "number not found" after the forloop ends?

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n,i;
    int arr[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
    int *ptr;
    printf("input the number you want to find:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(arr[i]==n)
        {
            ptr=&arr[i];
        printf("number '%d' is present in the array and it is the %d st/nd/rd/th term in the array.\n its address is: %d",n,i+1,ptr);
        }
}
```

**>i added else printf("number not found"); here but its also looping and printing a lot **

Comment: You need a separate variable to keep track of whether you've found the number or not.

Comment: Alternatively, `return` once the number is found. Then add your `printf` right after the loop, and it will be reached only in case the number was not found. Won't work if you want to report multiple matches.

Comment: @dbush   Thanks! I am so stupid, i searched it up and found the exact same thing that you suggested. Anyways I appreciate your help.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Interesting. I will try it out. I am a beginner as you can see but i thank you sincerely for taking out your time to provide me with the useful input. Thank you again kind sir.

Comment: Maybe also change `main()` type to `int main(void)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple... just add the print after the loop and add a return when you have a match.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n,i;
    int arr[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
    int *ptr;
    printf("input the number you want to find:\n");
    if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1)
    {
        // Input error
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==n)
        {
            ptr=&arr[i];
            printf("number '%d' is present in the array and it is the %d st/nd/rd/th term in the array.\n its address is: %p",n,i+1,(void*)ptr);
            return 0;  // Done... just end the program
        }
    }
    puts("not found");
}
```

BTW:

Notice that it shall be `int main(void)`

Notice that pointers are to be printed using `%p` with a cast to `(void*)`

Comment: What if he wants to do something more? It will work only in this trivial example

Comment: @0___________ True, if OP wants a multi-threaded solution to discover the largest prime known to man, this isn't the solution. Still, it's the simplest way to solve what OP asked for

Comment: It does not have to be multithreaded - your solution is not simple - it is simply bad.

Comment: @0___________ nah... it's not. It's solving what OP wants in a simple compliant manner - that's never bad

Comment: @0___________ If there's more to do, then soon enough the "search" functionality will be moved to its own function, where it will again be safe to return early, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the call of printf outside the for loop. For example

```
int *ptr = NULL;

printf("input the number you want to find:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

for( i = 0; ptr == NULL && i < 5; i++ )
{
    if ( arr[i] == n )
    {
        ptr = arr + i;
    }
}

if ( ptr != NULL )
{
    printf("number '%d' is present in the array and it is the %td st/nd/rd/th term in the array.\n its address is: %p\n", 
           n, ptr - arr + 1, ( void * )ptr );
}
else
{
    printf( "number %d is not present in the array.\n", n );
}
```

Also do not use magic numbers like `5`. Instead use named constants. And declare variables in minimal scopes where they are used.
And using the conversion specifier `%d` with a pointers has undefined behavior. You need to use the conversion specifier `%p`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
    
    int n = 0;
    
    printf( "input the number you want to find (default is %d): ", n );
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    
    int *ptr = NULL;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; ptr == NULL && i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( arr[i] == n )
        {
            ptr = arr + i;
        }
    }

    if ( ptr != NULL )
    {
        printf( "number '%d' is present in the array and it is the %td st/nd/rd/th term in the array.\n its address is: %p\n", 
                n, ptr - arr + 1, ( void * )ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "number %d is not present in the array.\n", n );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
input the number you want to find (default is 0): 3
number '3' is present in the array and it is the 3 st/nd/rd/th term in the array.
 its address is: 0x7ffefecb1778
```

Comment: maybe he wants to print all occurences.

Comment: @0___________ He wrote explicitly that he want to find a number.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Wow, I thought it was only a simple program that people would laugh at but such a simple can be done in so many interesting ways by so many interesting people

Answer (score -1):

1. Always check the return value of the `scanf`!!
2. Initialize pointer to NULL. If nothing found it will remain NULL
3. Use the correct format for the address (`%p`), and cast pointer to `(void *)` before passing to `printf`
4. `main` return type is `int`.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int arr[]={5,4,3,5,2,5,1};
    int *ptr = NULL;
    printf("input the number you want to find:\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&n) == 1)
    {
        for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);i++)
            if(arr[i]==n)
            {
                ptr=&arr[i];
                printf("number '%d' is present in the array and it is the %zu st/nd/rd/th term in the array.\n its address is: %p",n,i+1, (void *)ptr);
            }
        if(!ptr) printf("NUMBER NOT FOUND!!!!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("SCANF ERROR\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6zcE4nnz8

Comment: @yano no. There is only one statement in for loop - `if`

Comment: ah, you're right. My preference is brackets for clarity, got confused here

Comment: @0___________ so many things to learn and still a very long way to go for me.